# Views 3: display "block" doesn't show full node

Tags: 7, views, theming

I would like to show full node including comments in views. Everything is ok if I choose display "page" but in case of "block" all comments disappear from the view only content and link "add comment". What is wrong in my case and how to correct it? I need a block with full node content including comments.

My parameters in views:

Format:
Format: Slideshow
Show: Content; All (I also cheked "show comments" and "show links")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which module are you using for slideshow format ?

Comment: views slideshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select teaser view instead of full content you can see comments in your block.

If you see implementation of [`comment_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_node_view/7) comments are displayed only in node lading pages.

```
if ($node->comment && $view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node) && empty($node->in_preview)) {
  $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
}
```

If you enable the same block in node landing pages you can see the comments in your view.

If you enable the block other than node landing pages, then you cannot see the comments because of `node_is_page($node)` condition i think.